# Problems with Microsoft Wireless Keyboard 5000

Tags: 11.04, keyboard-layout

I have this keyboard, and I installed Ubuntu 11.04 without configure my keyboard correctly. Now, every time I turn on my computer I have to change it the layout from "USA" to "Brazil":

[image]

I tried to remoging the "USA" from list and click "Apply-System-Wide...", but after restart the layout always return to USA.

Any idea to keep the layout in "Brazil"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried setting the keyboard at the login screen? Click your user name and from the middle menu select other and you will find six keyboard options for Brazil.

Regards.